# plz Help me Login loop 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login

plz someone help me. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my graphic card GTX 960M so I installed Version : 410.93

I installed NVIDIA driver and rebooted. 
then I get stuck in login loop.
I found other people's same symptoms and resolutions.
I tried but all failed..

I don't know what is wrong.

**I tried the following resolution**

---

I looked at `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, but no error message

and when I installed NVIDIA, I add `blacklist nouveau` in `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
so I remove that typing.

and I typed `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` to delete drivers but
then I get lots of messages `can't remove cause no install`

and I typed `sudo dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` and did not get any response so I think driver was successfully deleted.

and I typed `nvidia-smi` I think it is no respond too
but ubuntu show me 'Driver Version: 410.93(i installed) CUDA Version: 10.0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I can't remove driver..

and typed `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` 
next, typed `echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` 
next, typed `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
next reboot!

but failed..

**Another resolution**

---

In tty3
typed `chown username:username .Xauthority` 
(~~~.ICEauthority, too)
and checked `ls -ld /tmp - drwxrwxrwt`
and typed `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`
and typed `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
and re login but failed .....

I can't format ubuntu... I have important files in ubuntu ..

plz knows me what can I do..